# Coulomb potential as a Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

It is well known from theory that the Coulomb potential can be obtained as a Fourier transform in the following way:

$$ \int \frac{\mathrm{d}^3p}{\left( 2 \pi \right)^3} \frac{e^{\mathrm{i} \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{r}}}{\mathbf{p}^2+m^2} =  \frac{e^{-rm}}{4 \pi r} \hspace{20pt} r \equiv \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$

(The mass term is here for mathematical convergence reasons, one can set the mass to zero after the transform. The Fourier transform also has a precise physical meaning, but that's out of the scope of this question.) I am trying to reproduce this result with Wolfram Mathematica; skipping some unnecessary constants I use the following code:

```
FourierTransform[1/(k*k + q*q + r*r + m*m), {k, q, r}, {x, y, z}]
```

which does not yield the expected result... I'm not an expert of Mathematica, by any means, but I cannot see why it gets this Fourier transform wrong.

Comment: If it's not a charade, could you please give use the (unexpected) output?

Comment: @F'x In 2D it fails to evaluate the output with the mass term. In 3D it gets stuck for ages thinking and then gives the input as output (not able to solve it, I suppose).

I remember that in 2D the mass is not needed for convergence, so I've tried and the output is:

    1/2 (-HeavisideTheta[-x] (2 EulerGamma + Log[-x - I y] + 
      Log[-x + I y]) - 
   HeavisideTheta[x] (2 EulerGamma + Log[x - I y] + Log[x + I y]))

while I was expecting:

$k \ln(r)$

Comment: I'm fine with the logs, but the EulerGamma is completely unexpected!

Comment: It often helps to assist *Mathematica* with a little preliminary analysis.  Upon observing the integral is spherically symmetric, you may set $\mathbf{r}=(r,0,0)$ and perform the integration over the first coordinate.  (Set $m=0$; you don't need this term for convergence.)  The residual symmetry suggests using polar coordinates, in which the integration is immediate and yields $1/(4\pi r)$.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem here is that *Mathematica* doesn't recognize `{x, y, z}` as some kind of a vector object that should be treated as grouped together; instead, it substitutes in three independent variables, and probably starts integrating them one by one. The result is a very complicated integral.

If you do the coordinate transformation yourself, you can reproduce the result. Simply use $\mathrm dp = \mathrm d\|p\|\|p\|^2\mathrm d\vartheta\sin(\vartheta)$ to transform to spherical. The resulting integral can be calculated:

```
Assuming[pAbs >= 0 && m > 0 && r > 0,
    (1/(2*Pi)^3)*Integrate[ (* phi integral *)
        Integrate[ (* |p| integral *)
            Integrate[ (* theta integral *)
                (Exp[I*r*pAbs*Cos[pTheta]]/(pAbs^2 + m^2))*pAbs^2*Sin[pTheta],
                {pTheta, 0, Pi}
            ],
            {pAbs, 0, Infinity}
        ],
        {pPhi, 0, 2*Pi}
    ]
]
```

> $\dfrac{e^{-mr}}{4\pi r}$

Comment: I can't reproduce the result, if I copy your code and paste it into a new Mathematica workbook I get:

    -(Sinh[m r]/(4 \[Pi] r))

however, this is clearly the way to go! :-) Answer accepted!

Comment: I can't reproduce your irreproducability: http://i.imgur.com/nhzZ2.png - Did you try evaluating using a fresh kernel?

Comment: Thank you this was really helpful to solving Fourier transform in Jacobi Polynomial