# Fourier transform of Exp[x]/x

Tags: bugs, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

Could you please explain why Mathematica gives the following expression when taking Fourier transform of $\exp(\lambda z)/\lambda$?
$$\frac{-\log(-z)+\log(z)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$
Why the answer does not depend on $x$?

The source code is as the following:

```
In[1]:= FourierTransform[Exp[λ z]/λ,λ,x]
Out[1]= (-Log[-z]+Log[z])/Sqrt[2 π]
```

Comment: I'll venture a guess. The FT does not exist, the FT code fails to catch that, calls `Integrate` with `GenerateConditions->False`, and gets the strange result in that way.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau That can't be right; if FourierTransform calls Integrate, there wouldn't be any point of having FourierTransform in the first place.

Comment: @QuantumDot that can't be right: FourierTransform is very complex, and it *may* call Integrate in some specific cases...

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform `Integrate` is a more general function than `FourierTransform`.  If anything, I would expect `Integrate` to make calls to `FourierTransform` for classes of integrals that are of the Fourier form -- not the other way around.

Comment: @QuantumDot I would assume that `FourierTransform` first does a table lookup to see if the function matches any patterns it knows the FT of, and then falls back on doing the integration the old fashioned way.  Admittedly, im neither a mathematician or computer scientist, so I'm curious how else would it work?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform and Jason-with-the-even-longer-moniker are correct. FT sometimes calls `Integrate`, never the reverse. `Integrate` itself should probably use more table lookup, like the FT code does, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Oh ok, I can confirm your guess: `Trace[FourierTransform[Exp[λ z]/λ, λ, 
  x], _Integrate, TraceInternal -> True]` reveals calls to `Integrate`.  I was so sure of myself that I would've placed a bet that `Integrate` calls `FourierTransform` and not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some commenters mentioned that the strange expression that Mathematica gives as a Fourier transform of `Exp[\[Lambda] z]/\[Lambda]` is a bug. If you are curious what the actual Fourier Transform is, you may find some insights in the related questions (e.g. [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4380/coulomb-potential-as-a-fourier-transform?rq=1)).

Comment: That FT does not exist. And that link involves unrelated FTs.