# Non-numerical values

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I want to numerically integrate

```
l[t_?NumericQ]:=(Cos[-3.2 kx]Cos[-0.999957 t * kz])/(0.0000859982 kz^2+kx^2+ky^2);

NIntegrate[l[t],{kx,-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]},{ky,-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]},{kz,-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}]
```

but get the following error

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand l[t] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{[Infinity],0.},{[Infinity],0.},{[Infinity],0.}}.

As you can see I've already tried the `?NumericQ` method, but it didn't change anything, the error appears either way. What can I do?

When I change the integration boundaries to avoid the ones that cause a problem according to the error message I still get the same warning but with the changed values, which I also don't understand.

Comment: `NIntegrate` is a pure numeric solver, `t` should be numeric, too.

Comment: The next step that I do is to plot it for `{t, -0.2, 0.2}`, is this error of importance in that case?

Comment: Also, if I try to NIntegrate `l` with a random number instead of `t`, like `l[0]` I still get the same error 
> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand (Cos[3.2 kx] Cos[0.999957 kz t])/(kx^2+ky^2+0.0000859982 kz^2) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{\[Infinity],0.},{\[Infinity],0.},{\[Infinity],0.}}.

Comment: Then it's merely a warning. Remember to `Clear[l]` before you define `l[t_?NumericQ]`.

Comment: As @xzczd metioned you should define something like `int[t_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[(Cos[-3.2 kx] Cos[-0.999957 t*kz])/(0.0000859982 kz^2 + 
      kx^2 + ky^2) // 
   Rationalize[#, 
     0] &, {kx, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {ky, -\[Infinity], \
\[Infinity]}, {kz, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]`. But MMA gives message "numerical integration converges to slowly"

Comment: Thank you all for your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a multidimensional integral with a highly-oscillating integrand. This makes a problem since the Methods for integrating highly-oscillating functions work better for 1D integrals. In your case, one can "help" Mma to solve this integral by integrating it over x and y first.  I will also replace 0.999957 by 1, while  `3.2` and `0.0000859982` - by `Rationalize[3.2]` and `Rationalize[0.00009]`:

```
  int = Assuming[{z \[Element] Reals && z != 0}, 
  Integrate[(Cos[-Rationalize[3.2] x] Cos[-t*z])/(Rationalize[
        0.00009]*z^2 + x^2 + 
      y^2), {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {y, -\[Infinity], \
\[Infinity]}]]

(*  2 \[Pi] BesselK[0, 6/125 Sqrt[2/5] Abs[z]] Cos[t z] *)
```

Now let us define the following function:

```
f[t_] := NIntegrate[
   2 \[Pi] BesselK[0, 6/125 Sqrt[2/5] Abs[z]] Cos[
     t z], {z, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, Method -> "LevinRule"];
```

and make a table:

```
lst = ParallelTable[{t, f[t]}, {t, -0.2, 0.2, 0.005}];
```

yielding this:

```
ListPlot[lst]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you for your input! This helps a lot with problems that I had with this function.