# Can't integrate a highly oscillatory integrand

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have a long formula

```
-0.0579484 kx ((Sin[-3.2 kx] Cos[Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] t])/Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] (Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2]/(0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + 0.00008649 kz^2) + 1/Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] (kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2)/(-kx^2 - ky^2 - 0.00008649 kz^2)) + (Cos[-3.2 kx] Sin[Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] t])/Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] ((-0.999957 kz)/(0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + 0.00008649 kz^2) + (-0.999957 kz)/(-kx^2 - ky^2 - 0.00008649 kz^2)) + (Sin[-3.2 kx] Cos[-0.999957 kz t] + Cos[-3.2 kx] Sin[-0.999957  kz t])/(-0.0232723 - kx^2 - ky^2 - 0.00008649 kz^2) + Sin[-3.2 kx] 0.0232723/(0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2)1/(-kx^2 - ky^2 - 0.00008649 kz^2))
```

which I want to integrate over $\int kx \, ky \, kz$ and plot over $t$.

I can integrate the elements of the sum separately and add them at the end. The elements are

**I:**

```
-0.0579484 kx ((Sin[3.2 kx] Cos[Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] t])/Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2]/(0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + 0.00008649 kz^2))
```

**II:**

```
-0.0579484 kx ((Sin[3.2 kx] Cos[Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] t])/Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] 1/Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] (kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2)/(-kx^2 - ky^2 - 0.00008649 kz^2))
```

**III:**

```
-0.0579484 kx ((Cos[3.2 kx] Sin[Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] t])/Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] (0.999957 kz)/(0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + 0.00008649 kz^2))
```

**IV:**

```
-0.0579484 kx ((Cos[3.2 kx] Sin[Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] t])/Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] (0.999957 kz)/(-kx^2 - ky^2 - 0.00008649 kz^2))
```

**V:**

```
-0.0579484 kx ((Sin[3.2 kx] Cos[0.999957 kz t] + Cos[3.2 kx] Sin[0.999957  kz t])/(0.0232723 - kx^2 - ky^2 - 0.00008649 kz^2))
```

**VI:**

```
-0.0579484 kx (Sin[3.2 kx] 0.0232723/(0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2)1/(-kx^2 - ky^2 - 0.00008649 kz^2))
```

The V and VI is the only part which I know how to compute with correct results. The method is as follows: First, I Integrate the formula V analytically over $ky$ and $kz$

```
f = Assuming[{kz \[Element] Reals && kz != 0 && kx \[Element] Reals && ky \[Element] Reals && t \[Element] Reals}, Integrate[-0.0579484 kx ((Sin[3.2 kx] Cos[0.999957 kz t] + Cos[3.2 kx] Sin[0.999957  kz t])/(0.0232723 - kx^2 - ky^2 - 0.00008649 kz^2)), {kz, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {ky, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]]
```

Then, I numerically integrate the result over $kx$

```
Nf[t_] := NIntegrate[fV2, {kx, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, Method -> "LevinRule"];
```

(Integrating first over $kx$ and $ky$ and then numerically over $kz$ works too)

Finally I plot the result as

```
Plot[Nf[t], {t, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {{-0.2, 0.2}, All}]
```

The above method was provided here
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/276353/88922
and works only for the V and VI case.

For I-IV I tried integrating over $kx$, $ky$, $kz$ separately and for I-II Mathematica doesn't provide any result, for III-IV integrating over $kx$ or $kz$ gives 0, over $ky$ - nothing.

Method of V works on VI as wellAny ideas how to approach the topic? How to integrate the I-IV formulas over $kx$, $ky$, $kz$?

P.S. I couldn't integrate analytically over all of the three k variables at once - no results, and integrating fully numerically is too slow.

Comment: You might try rationalizing all your numbers to exact values and increasing the `WorkingPrecision` in your `NIntegrate` statements.

Comment: Exact solvers (like `Integrate`) and inexact coefficients (like decimal-point numbers) sometimes don't mix well (because, for instance, round-off error prevent cancellation of what should be equal terms). So rationalizing as Bill suggested might help with `Integrate`, too.

Comment: The numbers need to stay as they are. Regardless, I tried changing them into integers, or more, putting 1 instead of them to simplify it even more but the results of `Integrate` are the same - integrals that weren't computing still aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate manages one instance eg $$\int dx (\sum \frac{\sin \dots}{\sqrt{\dots}}\dots)$$ but the result is an $\text{Ei}$-function of the other variables. So there is no chance to perform further interation steps $$\int( \dots  )\ dy \ dz$$ .

NIntegrate needs a threefold integral for any time t, because the algorithm does not accept variables.

Its impossible to put it inside a Plot statement for unspecified t-points, because on has no control of execution times and memory used. A ListPlot for an NIntegrate list over a list of t-values may work.

So, a way is to NIntegrate for a list of t-values over a 3d lattice with relatively few points per sin-period and interpolate the 4d lattice separately to get an interpolating function. For a visual Plot management, relatively small numbers of lattice point numbers are satisfying the objectives.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understood what you mean. 

In the first part you're saying that because of the result of a single integration further ones aren't possible - wouldn't that be true also for the case V - which works just fine with a double integral? Besides, integrals I-IV don't compute with `Integrate` even for a single variable and I don't know why or what to do with it.

In the next part, are you suggesting to deal with the integrals fully numerically but to plot them using `ListPlot` instead of `Plot`?

Answer (score 0):

It  diverges if I am not mistaken. Here are my arguments. Let us expand the integrand

```
Expand[-0.0579484 kx ((Sin[-3.2 kx] Cos[
     Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] t])/
  Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + 
    kz^2] (Sqrt[
     0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2]/(0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + 
      0.00008649 kz^2) + 
   1/Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] (kx^2 + ky^2 + 
       kz^2)/(-kx^2 - ky^2 - 
       0.00008649 kz^2)) + (Cos[-3.2 kx] Sin[
     Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] t])/
  Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + 
    kz^2] ((-0.999957 kz)/(0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + 
      0.00008649 kz^2) + (-0.999957 kz)/(-kx^2 - ky^2 - 
      0.00008649 kz^2)) + (Sin[-3.2 kx] Cos[-0.999957 kz t] + 
   Cos[-3.2 kx] Sin[-0.999957 kz t])/(-0.0232723 - kx^2 - ky^2 - 
   0.00008649 kz^2) + 
Sin[-3.2 kx] .0232723/(0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2) 1/(-kx^2 - 
    ky^2 - 0.00008649 kz^2))]
```

> `(0.00134859 kx Sin[ 3.2 kx])/((-kx^2 - ky^2 - 0.00008649 kz^2) (0.0232723 + kx^2 +  ky^2 + kz^2)) + ( 0.0579484 kx Cos[0.999957 kz t] Sin[3.2 kx])/(-0.0232723 - kx^2 -  ky^2 - 0.00008649 kz^2) + ( 0.0579484 kx Cos[Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] t] Sin[ 3.2 kx])/(0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + 0.00008649 kz^2) + ( 0.0579484 kx^3 Cos[Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] t] Sin[ 3.2 kx])/((-kx^2 - ky^2 - 0.00008649 kz^2) (0.0232723 + kx^2 +  ky^2 + kz^2)) + ( 0.0579484 kx ky^2 Cos[Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] t] Sin[ 3.2 kx])/((-kx^2 - ky^2 - 0.00008649 kz^2) (0.0232723 + kx^2 +  ky^2 + kz^2)) + ( 0.0579484 kx kz^2 Cos[Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] t] Sin[ 3.2 kx])/((-kx^2 - ky^2 - 0.00008649 kz^2) (0.0232723 + kx^2 +  ky^2 + kz^2)) + ( 0.0579484 kx Cos[3.2 kx] Sin[0.999957 kz t])/(-0.0232723 - kx^2 -  ky^2 - 0.00008649 kz^2) + ( 0.0579459 kx kz Cos[3.2 kx] Sin[ Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] t])/((-kx^2 - ky^2 -  0.00008649 kz^2) Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2]) + ( 0.0579459 kx kz Cos[3.2 kx] Sin[ Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] t])/((0.0232723 + kx^2 +  ky^2 + 0.00008649 kz^2) Sqrt[0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2])`

and consider a term of the above sum

```
0.0579484*kx*Cos[0.999957 kz t]*Sin[3.2 kx]/(-0.0232723 - kx^2 - ky^2 - 0.00008649*kz^2)
```

Then

```
Integrate[Rationalize[(0.0579484` kx Cos[0.999957` kz t] Sin[3.2` kx])/
(-0.0232723` -   kx^2 - ky^2 - 0.00008649` kz^2), 0], {ky, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {kx, kz} > -Infinity]
```

> `(144871 kx \[Pi] Cos[(999957 kz t)/1000000] Sin[(16 kx)/5])/(250 Sqrt[ 2327230 + 100000000 kx^2 + 8649 kz^2])`

The above expression behaves as $c_1\sin \left(\frac {16} 5 kx\right)$ when $kx\to \infty$ and  $c_2\sin \left(\frac {16} 5 kx\right)$ when $kx\to -\infty$ , where $c_1,c_2$ are real-valued constants. This implies the divergence of its integral over $kx$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ if $kz$ and $t$  are fixed.